# Will AWLL6077v2 Wireless N 300 USB Adapter

Tags: wireless, dual-boot

Will AWLL6077v2 Wireless N 300 USB Adapter
work with ubuntu running in dual-boot on a Macbook pro OSX 10.8?
The embedded chipset in AWLL6077v2 is Realtek RTL8192SU
I can get support driver for Unix (Linux) from Realtek for
       Linux Kernel 2.6.18~2.6.38 and Kernel 3.0.2
       Android 1.6~2.3 and 4.0

Question: will these drivers run on ubuntu 12.04 and/or ubuntu 13 kernels

Answer (score 0):

Yes they will work with Ubuntu kernel versions of Ubuntu 12.04 and 13.04. There is huge discussion there and Its already solved . i can not extract the answer for you . you have to read it once.

https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-nettool/+question/120351